# Creating an array with 2 same values as keys

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I'm reading an excel, and in the headers there are 2 equal values, for example "HELLO" and "HELLO", but when I create an array or object from those headers, using those values as key of each value, they are overwritten since They have the same value. How can I do to keep both records?

```
$dataE = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($archivo_procesar, function($reader) {
    $reader->each(function ($row){
        dump($row);
    });
    dd();
});
```

The excel that I'm reading is something like this:

----| GOD | GOD | HELLO | HELLO | PHP | LARAVEL | STACK | STACK

S1 |

S2 |

S3 |

S4 |

Comment: Whatever you like. Rename it, make it an array, etc...

Comment: I need those values has the same name. I will edit the answer with a example of the file.

Comment: Use a different storage technique?  Instead of `$array["HELLO"] = 1`, why not `$array[] = "HELLO"`?  The former is employed commonly as a strategy to remove duplicates, which is what you don't want.